# Problems with instalation of my distributable symfony2 bundle

Tags: symfony, bundle

I can't succesfull install my first distributable bundle in any Symfony2 project because I'm making mistakes with the configuration of the bundle.

My Bundle: https://github.com/KdrMkLabs/TicketBundle

When you install the bundle following the install instructions and using composer like is usually, its works. But when you run the website its occurs the following exception:

[image]

I dont know why this happens, Could you help me to understand what is the correct way to set the configurations for a distributable bundle?

Thank you.

---

**KDRTicketBundle configuration:**

[image]

composer.json

```json
{
    "name": "kdrmklabs/ticket-bundle",
    "type": "symfony-bundle",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "KDRMKLabs\\TicketBundle\\": "" }
    }
}
```

```php
// file: KDRTicketBundle.php

namespace KDRMKLabs\TicketBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class KDRTicketBundle extends Bundle
{
}
```

Notes:

- Im using the namespaces `namespace KDRMKLabs\TicketBundle\*...` in all my project classes (controllers, services, entities).
- This Bundle works fine in the developing project when is allocated in src/ directory like every symfony2 bundle when is developing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PSR-0 autoloading requires the *full namespace* to be represented by directories. In this case, this means the bundle class should live in `kdrmklabs/ticket-bundle/KdrmkLabs/TicketBundle/KdrmkLabsTicketBundle.php`.

Of course, having these extra directories is plain stupid. That's why there is PSR-4 autoloading. This standards strips the configured namespace prefix from the path.

So the solution is to change `"psr-0": { ... }` to `"psr-4": { ... }`

Comment: I solved my problem. The name of DependencyInjection/KDRTicketExtension.php was different to the name of parameter defined in DependencyInjection/Configuration.php.  And psr-0 was wrong like you said. Thank you.